# Questions of .urdf.xacro file

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 3 questions:
First, what is the .urdf.xacro file?
Second, how convert .urdf.xacro to .urdf, which can be visualized in Rviz?
Third, whether there is other ways to visualize .urdf.xacro file?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155161/questions-of-.urdf.xacro-file/) by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2014-04-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might have read an article on this page ( http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20Xacro%20to%20Clean%20Up%20a%20URDF%20File ). Xacro file is macro file of urdf. Xacro file allow us to make it easier to maintain the robot description files. So you can convert urdf.xacro to urdf in launch.

```
< param name="robot_description" 
   command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find pr2_description)/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro'" />
```

If you have a turtlebot, I think that you have launched minimal.launch.  The description.launch.xml in `/turtlebot_bringup/launch/includes` also describes robot_description for a turtlebot. Rviz need a robot_description to show a robot model.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2014-04-19**:
Thanks, and I found "rosrun xacro xacro.py `rospack find turtlebot_description`/robots/graveyard/turtlebot.urdf.xacro -o ~/exp1_ws/src/trunk/urdf_tutorial/turtlebot.urdf
" is also worked! But actually I want to rviz the complete turtlebot. I'm failed in processing turtlebot.urdf.xacro, do you know how?

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-20**:
Hello @Yantian_Zha : I'm sorry, I just answer your original question. If you have not executed simulator and are beginner of ROS, I recommend you to try segbot simulator of this page( http://answers.ros.org/question/123116/how-to-execute-navigation-experimental/ )

**Comment by [Yantian_Zha](https://answers.ros.org/users/13706/yantian_zha/) on 2014-04-20**:
Thanks, Ken_in_JAPAN!